# Yum error: Package requires libhogweed.so, Removing nettle-2.7.1

Tags: redhat, yum

Currently I am attempting to install some packages with yum (through ansible, but I don't think ansible is the cause for this error  as I get a similar error when trying to install by hand)

Currently on a Red Hat Linux 7 installation, I am transitioning from a Red Hat 6 build.

This is some text to bypass the details requirement of stackoverflow, there really aren't any more details that I can provide. I'm just trying to put the error in a code block so that the formatting doesn't make it unreadable.

```
Error: 
  Package: 
    gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)
  Requires: 
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
  Removing: 
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
    ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)

Error: 
  Package: 
    gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)
  Requires: 
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Removing:
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)             
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Updated By: 
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)  
    ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)

Error:
  Package: 
    gnutls-dane-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires: 
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Removing: 
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)        
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)   
    ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)

Error: 
  Package:
    tigervnc-server-minimal-1.8.0-19.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)        
  Requires:
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Removing: 
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)            
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)           
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)   
    ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)\nError: Package: libcanberra-0.30-9.el7.i686 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libasound.so.2

Error:
  Package:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libgmp.so.3()(64bit)

Error:
  Package:
    libcanberra-0.30-9.el7.i686 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)

Error: 
  Package:
    gnutls-utils-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Removing:
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)            
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)
    ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)

Error:
  Package:
    gnutls-utils-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
  Removing:
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)             
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)   
    ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)

Error:
  Package: 
    gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.10.4-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8) 
  Requires:
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Removing:
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)              
    libnettle.so.4()(64bit)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64) 
    ~libnettle.so.6()(64bit)

Error:
  Package:
    gnutls-dane-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires: 
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit) 
  Removing:
    nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.8)              
    libhogweed.so.2()(64bit)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64) 
    ~libhogweed.so.4()(64bit)

Error:
  Package: 
    libcanberra-0.30-9.el7.i686 (Default_Organization_CentOS_7_CentOS_7_x86_64)
  Requires:
    libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)
  Updated By:
    nettle-3.2-2.el6.x86_64 (Default_Organization_EPEL_EPEL_6_x86_64)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a mix of `el6` and `el7` packages.  You need to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm currently trying to transition a system from RHEL6 to RHEL7, do you have any advice for how to fix the issue?